# writing the equivalent of an empty cell in excel to a txt

Tags: r

I have data formatted like so

```
        Weight Nested      Procedure   Stimulus CorrectAnswer
514       1           TrialProcedure cumulative             d
472       1           TrialProcedure     cull               d
533       1           TrialProcedure    hello               d
5201      1           TrialProcedure   cincoovi             s
4671      1           TrialProcedure     splesh             s
5001      1           TrialProcedure    prevuka             s
```

When I write this to a file with

```
write.table(y, file = paste("Day",a, " ",k, ".txt", sep=""), sep = "\t", row.names=FALSE)
```

It creates a txt which my program(Invalid attribute error) can't read. If I go manually into excel and highlight the cells in Nested + clear I can read it. Is there a way to format them in R so I don't need to do this?

Comment: Does your "Nested" column contain value 1 or NA? Could you paste str(y), please.

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta seems to be on the right track here - problems may occur is you have blank spaces in your column names. Also, I don't know if this is just a copy/paste problem, but your `$stimulus` values are not lined up, and you may need to also make sure that you do not have some unwanted leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell from your sample data if "Nested" is part of the previous column's name, ie "Weight Nested" or if it is a separate column with blank values.

If it part of the column name then a solution would be to use `make.names`:

```
  names(yourData) <- make.names(names(yourData))
```

If it is a blank column, fill it with NA's

```
  yourData$Nested <- NA

  # or 
  yourData$Nested[yourData$Nested == ""] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do this write.table writes the string NA to the column. Is there any way to fix that?